# What could possibly this CP Multiplier be related to?

Tags: pokemon-go

On lines 574 - 619 of this [data dump](https://gist.github.com/KazWolfe/68e10ebf1ed41ae1ae6de2350d5de884) from the app there is some sort of CP multiplier. What could this possibly mean and what is it most likely related to?

Is it the CP your Pokemon can reach at its MAX or is it related to evolution or powering up or wild pokemon?

Comment: Why this would have been downvoted is beyond me? Anyway I had the same question so thank you for asking :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Pokémon's max CP will be reached with their final evolution at max level. That's pretty much it. There is no real difference in the source of the Pokémon, whether you hatched or caught it. But there seems to be a slightly difference is possible max CP a Pokémon of the same family can reach. However, I have no proof for this since I haven't maxed out any Pokémon, so you can as well ignore it.

The modifier from your file just tells you how much CP it currently can have based on the current level. Let's say you have a Pokémon with a final max CP of 2000 at most. 
At level 40 (0.7903) the max CP it can reach is 2000 * 0.7903 = 1580.6

This does not have anything to do with their evolution stage as this is calculated beforehand. This is the so-called evolution modfier, which can vary from 1.1 (Caterpie - Metapod) to 12.1 (Magikarp - Gyarados).

The maths for that would be:

Total max CP: *type_max_cp x evolution_modifier = evolved_max_cp*

Current level's max CP: *evolved_max_xp x level_modifier = current_max_cp*

Example:

- Bulbasaur * 1.6 = Ivysaur
- Ivysaur * 1.6 = Venusaur
- Venusaur * 0.7903 = Level 40 Venusaur

The order is completely up to you. Due to the nature of multiplication you can evolve or max out the level at your convenience with no difference in the outcome.

Comment: So I best save any Evolution I aim to keep towards end-game after Level40 (or higher when/if they up the cap). As I currently have caught many pidgeys and have all three evolutions. If I redo the evolutions at Level40 (or whatever the cap will be) later on my birds will be stronger and have higher max strength ?

Comment: No. 1.6 * 0.7 is the same like 0.7 * 1.6, it doesn't matter when you evolve them. The result will be the same. It's better to wait with evolving, though. With higher levels you can catch higher CP Pokémon, which require much less stardust to power them up. Other than that there is no difference.

Answer (score 0):

In your link appears:

CP Multiplier / Level

```
 -Possibly used to calculate Pokemon Max CP?

   (???) CurrCPCap = PokemonMaxCP * LevelMultiplier
```

is related the pokemon max cp and the trainer level (line 619 could indicate Max Level 40 :O )